# Knockout Js render differently with if data-bind based on a Json value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've got a similar to the below code and i want to render differently the **capital with cityName Barnsley** and differently a city with some other name.
What is the right way to do the **if binding**? Do i have to put cityName as observable to work?

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: planets">
    <li>
        Planet: <b data-bind="text: name"> </b>
        <div data-bind="if: capital">
            Capital: <b data-bind="text: capital.cityName"> </b>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>


<script>
    ko.applyBindings({
        planets: [
            { name: 'Mercury', capital: null }, 
            { name: 'Earth', capital: { cityName: 'Barnsley' } }        
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Ok Still no success My json is this:

```
var Images = {
    "ImageInfo": [
        {
            "thumbs": [
                {
                    "IMAGE": "url(http://...d38508d4f183.jpg)",
                    "type": "img"
                },
                {
                    "IMAGE": "url(http://...d38508d4f183.jpg)",
                    "type": "video"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "thumbs": [
                {
                    "IMAGE": "url(http://...d38508d4f183.jpg)",
                    "type": "img"
                },
                {
                    "IMAGE": "url(http://...d38508d4f183.jpg)",
                    "type": "video"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

The HTML i want to achieve is the below:

```
    <div id="Images">
        <div data-bind="foreach: ViewModelB">

            <div data-bind="foreach: thumbs">
                <div data-bind="if: type == 'img'">
                    <a style="width: 50px; height: 50px; float: left; display: block; background-size: cover; margin-left: 15px; cursor: pointer;" data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: IMAGE_PATH }"></a>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="if: type == 'video'">
                    <p style="width: 50px; height: 50px; float: left; display: block; background-size: cover; margin-left: 15px; cursor: pointer;" data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: IMAGE_PATH }"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
var ViewModelB = ko.mapping.fromJS(Images);
        ko.applyBindings(ViewModelB, document.getElementById("Images"));
</script>
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/Rpgnc/

Comment: I know that the above code works it's copy paste from Knockoutjs documentation. My question is how to render differently the capital with cityName Barnsley and differently a capital with cityName : asdad. Is there a way to write data-bind:"if cityName==Barnsley" render the following ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, it doesnt have to be observable if its not going change later on, you can do if statements and render differently , something like below

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: planets">
    <li>
        Planet: <b data-bind="text: name"> </b>
        <div data-bind="if: capital">
              <!-- ko if:capital.cityName=='Barnsley' -->
            Capital: <b data-bind="text: capital.cityName"> </b>
              <!-- /ko -->
             <!-- ko if:capital.cityName=='asdad' -->
            Capital: <i data-bind="text: capital.cityName"> </b>
              <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or you can also do switch case https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case

Comment: I'm not in the office at the moment, tomorrow morning i will try both suggestions and i will provide feedback. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I tried knockout-switch-case as you suggested and it worked like a charm but i still want to know where is the error in my code :/

Comment: in  your code you are converting 'Images' into an observable so you should treat 'type' as a  function like "if: type() == 'img'", try this. KO example it was not treated like a function, because the condition is verified by knockout which knows to deal with both observables or non-observables using 'ko.unwrapObservable()' method, in when you explicitly verify the condition, you need to take care. Read more on unwrapObservable. Btw this piece was missing when i saw this question first.

Comment: Dear Dhana Krishnasamy thank you very much for you help and guidance, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't have to be an observable (as long as it doesn't get changed afterwards; if it does, the change won't automatically be reflected in the view), and you got the proposed binding almost right: it should be `data-bind="if: cityName=='Barnsley'"` (note the colon and the quotes).